# ignore null values globally in JSON output in aspnet method

Tags: c#, asp.net, null, json.net, .net-6.0

newbie question: how do i make my JSON output ignore `null` values?  I don't want to necessarily set each individual property to ignore `null` (as in decorate each property with `[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]` ), and few different global methods I found and tried didn't work.
I am using .Net 6 and Newtonsoft.Json

I have this method in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ResponseJson> Post([FromBody] RequestJson value)
{
    DataProcessor processor = new DataProcessor(value);
    return processor.GetResults();
}
```

This is what `ResponseJson` looks like (with some properties omitted for brevity).

```
public class ResponseJson
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "items")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}   

public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "colour")]
    public string colour { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "parameters")]
    public ItemParameters parameters { get; set; }
}
```

`DataProcessor` doesn't set the `colour` (`null`), or doesn't set `ItemParameters` at all for some of the `Item`.  When looking at the response from calling this method, the JSON string looks like this:

```
{
    "items":
        [
            {
                "name":"abc",
                "colour": "blue",
                "parameters":{<a bunch of parameters>}
            },
            {
                "name":"def",
                "colour": null
                "parameters":null
            },
            {
                "name":"ghi",
                "colour": null,
                "parameters":null
            },
            {
                "name":"jkl",
                "colour": "red",
                "parameters":{<a bunch of parameters>}
            }
        ]
}
```

I want the properties with `null` values to be ignored completely so that it looks like this:

```
{
    "items":
        [
            {
                "name":"abc",
                "colour": "blue",
                "parameters":{<a bunch of parameters>}
            },
            {
                "name":"def"
            },
            {
                "name":"ghi"
            },
            {
                "name":"jkl",
                "colour": "red",
                "parameters":{<a bunch of parameters>}
            }
        ]
}
```

Comment: what is the advantage of ignoring the fields with nulls?  During bind the missing fields become null.

Comment: shorter string?

Comment: you could introduce error.  I would not parse the json string and remove unnecessary fields.  to difficult to know the functionality of the end consumer

Answer (score 7):

net core 6 web api, in program, add `AddJsonOptions` in your `AddControllers`

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{ 
   options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
});
```

in net core mvc

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
 options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
});
```

in minimal API create service

```
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    // Set this to true to ignore null or default values
    options.SerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
});
```

example complete using minimal API

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    // Set this to true to ignore null or default values
    options.SerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}


app.MapGet("/GetWeatherForecast", () => new Person { FirstName = "Gérald"});
app.Run();

public class Person
{
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
}
```

result without ignore null

```
{
  "FirstName": "Gérald",
  "LastName": null
}
```

result ignore null

```
{
  "firstName": "Gérald"
}
```

Comment: What about same thing in minimal api? There is no controllers.

Comment: @SaleCar I have updated the answer with an example using minimal api

Answer (score 4):

did you try this way?

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(o => {   o.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below codes in the `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` file, and it will work

```
services.AddMvc()
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
});
```

Seems the `JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues` field is obsolete now, so try the new approach as stated below:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For Minimal APIs running in DOTNET 7+ (probably 6 too) it is now as simple as the Minimal API Tutorial's section [Configure JSON Serialization Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/responses?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-json-serialization-options) shows. Just use `Builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions()` as per the excerpt bellow:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options => {
    options.SerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
    // set other desired options here...
    options.SerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true;
    options.SerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true;
});

var app = builder.Build();
```